# As of Chrome 90, Can't Modify Response Header for X-Frame-Options

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I had a Chrome extension that was working perfectly and recently (it seems as of Chrome 90) broke. The extension would load some pages into IFRAMES and it would remove the response x-frame-options header so that even sites that have set headers to prevent being IFRAMED could be IFRAMED. The code in background.js that does / did this is below.

However, as of Chrome 90 and above, this no longer works as I get a "site refused to connect" error in each of the IFRAMES. Is there a new way to do this?

```
function stripHeaders(headers) {
      return headers.filter(header => {
        let headerName = header.name.toLowerCase();
        return !(headerName === 'content-security-policy' || headerName === 'x-frame-options' || headerName === 'permissions-policy' || headerName === 'x-xss-protection' || headerName === 'x-content-type-options' || headerName === 'strict-transport-security' || headerName === 'expect-ct' || headerName === "expires" || headerName === "cache-control" || headerName === "pragma" || headerName == "cf-cache-status" || headerName == "cf-ray" || headerName == "cf-request-id" || headerName === "content-ecoding");
      })
    }

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
      console.log(stripHeaders(details.responseHeaders));
    return {
      responseHeaders: stripHeaders(details.responseHeaders)
    };
  }, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer a few minutes later. The key thing that seems to have changed is that one needs to add extraHeaders to "blocking" and "responseHeaders." Also, if you weren't already (which I was), one must include content-security-policy as one of the headers to get rid of, along with x-frame-options. The other headers don't matter. To give credit where it's due, I figured this out by viewing the code for a Chrome Extension called xframe_ignore on github (https://github.com/guilryder/chrome-extensions/tree/main/xframe_ignore).

```
function stripHeaders(headers) {
      return headers.filter(header => {
        let headerName = header.name.toLowerCase();
        return !(headerName === 'content-security-policy' || headerName === 'x-frame-options' || headerName === 'permissions-policy' || headerName === 'x-xss-protection' || headerName === 'x-content-type-options' || headerName === 'strict-transport-security' || headerName === 'expect-ct' || headerName === "expires" || headerName === "cache-control" || headerName === "pragma" || headerName == "cf-cache-status" || headerName == "cf-ray" || headerName == "cf-request-id" || headerName === "content-ecoding");
      })
    }

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
      console.log(stripHeaders(details.responseHeaders));
    return {
      responseHeaders: stripHeaders(details.responseHeaders)
    };
  }, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders", "extraHeaders"]);
```